# Trying to get output of ffprobe into variable

Tags: python

I am trying to grab the ffprobe values from the video file into a variable that I can compare against others or move the value into a database. The question I have; Is there a better way of doing it than below?

I don't like the multiple if/elif/line.startswith statements and I am not sure of split is the best way of getting the ffprobe values?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, subprocess, shlex, re, fnmatch
from subprocess import call 

videoDrop_dir="/mnt/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/test_drop"

for r,d,f in os.walk(videoDrop_dir):
    for files in f:
        print "Files: %s" % files
        if files.startswith(('._', '.')):
            print "This file: %s is not valid" % files
        elif files.endswith(('.mov', '.mpg', '.mp4', '.wmv', '.mxf')):
            fpath = os.path.join(r, files)
            def probe_file(fpath):
                cmnd = ['ffprobe', '-show_format', '-show_streams', '-pretty', '-loglevel', 'quiet', fpath]
                p = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                print files
                out, err = p.communicate()
                print "===============================OUTPUT START: %s ===============================" % files
                print out
                for line in out.split('\n'):
                line = line.strip()
                if line.startswith('codec_name='):
                    s = line 
                    codec_name = s.split('codec_name=', 1)
                    print "Codec is: %s" % codec_name[1]
                    codec_1 = codec_name[1]
                elif line.startswith('codec_type='): 
                    s = line 
                    codec_type = s.split('codec_type=', 1)
                    print "Codec type is: %s" % codec_type[1]
                    codec_type1 = codec_type[1]   
                elif line.startswith('codec_long_name=', 1):
                    s = line 
                    codec_long_name = s.split('codec_long_name=', 1)
                    print "Codec long name: %s" % codec_long_name[1]
                    codec_long_name = codec_long_name[1]
                elif line.startswith('format_long_name=', 1):
                    s = line 
                    format_long_name = s.split('format_long_name=', 1)
                    print "Format long name: %s" % format_long_name[1]
                    format_long_name = format_long_name[1]
                elif line.startswith('width='): 
                    s = line 
                    width = s.split('width=', 1)
                    print "Video pixel width is: %s" % width[1]
                    p_width = width[1]
                elif line.startswith('height='): 
                    s = line 
                    height = s.split('height=', 1)
                    print "Video pixel height is: %s" % height[1]
                    p_height = height[1]    
                elif line.startswith('bit_rate='):
                    s = line 
                    bit_rate = s.split('bit_rate=', 1)
                    print "Bit rate is: %s" % bit_rate[1]
                    bit_rate1 = bit_rate[1]
                elif line.startswith('display_aspect_ratio=', 1):
                    s = line 
                    display_aspect_ratio = s.split('display_aspect_ratio=', 1)
                    print "Display aspect ratio: %s" % display_aspect_ratio[1]
                    display_aspect_ratio1 = display_aspect_ratio[1]
                elif line.startswith('avg_frame_rate=', 1):
                    s = line 
                    avg_frame_rate = s.split('avg_frame_rate=', 1)
                    print "Average Frame Rate: %s" % avg_frame_rate[1]
                    avg_frame_rate1 = avg_frame_rate[1]

            print "===============================OUTPUT FINISH: %s ===============================" % files
            if err: 
                print "===============================ERROR: %s ===============================" % files
                print err
        probe_file(fpath)
    else:
        if not files.endswith(('.mov', '.mpg', '.mp4', '.wmv', '.mxf')):
            print "This file: %s is not a valid video file" % files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, subprocess, shlex, re, fnmatch
from subprocess import call 

videoDrop_dir="/mnt/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/test_drop"
```

Python convention is to ALL_CAPS for global constants

```
for r,d,f in os.walk(videoDrop_dir):
```

I suggest not using single letter variable names here, it just obfuscates the meanings.

```
    for files in f:
```

files is a single file, not plural, it should be file or filename.

```
        print "Files: %s" % files
        if files.startswith(('._', '.')):
```

Since ._ starts with . there is no reason to check both.

```
            print "This file: %s is not valid" % files
        elif files.endswith(('.mov', '.mpg', '.mp4', '.wmv', '.mxf')):
            fpath = os.path.join(r, files)
            def probe_file(fpath):
```

Why do you define a function inline and then just call it? Either get rid of the function or move the function outside of the loop and call it.

```
                cmnd = ['ffprobe', '-show_format', '-show_streams', '-pretty', '-loglevel', 'quiet', fpath]
```

Don't needlessly abbreivate, call it `command`

```
                p = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                print files
                out, err = p.communicate()
                print "===============================OUTPUT START: %s ===============================" % files
                print out
```

See subprocess.check_output. It calls the command returns the string so you can simplify this last but of code.

```
                for line in out.split('\n'):
                line = line.strip()
                if line.startswith('codec_name='):
                    s = line 
                    codec_name = s.split('codec_name=', 1)
                    print "Codec is: %s" % codec_name[1]
                    codec_1 = codec_name[1]
```

Rather then repeating this bunches of times, do something like

```
decoder_configuration = {}
for line in out.splitlines():
    if '=' in line:
        key, value = line.split('=')
        decoder_configuration[key] = value


Then all of the pieces of data will be held in decoder_configuration. You can do what you want with it from there.

            print "===============================OUTPUT FINISH: %s ===============================" % files
            if err: 
                print "===============================ERROR: %s ===============================" % files
                print err
        probe_file(fpath)
    else:
        if not files.endswith(('.mov', '.mpg', '.mp4', '.wmv', '.mxf')):
            print "This file: %s is not a valid video file" % files
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I really appreciate your help! I will try and put this into play right now

Comment: It worked. The only thing I did not manage to get working was the subprocess.check_output - but I will spend some time getting more familiar with subprocess calls. Again thank you